# CSES - Number Spiral - Java TLE

Tags: java, performance, time-limit-exceeded

My java code for CSES Introductory problem Number Spiral gives TLE for large inputs, like

Input :

100000
170550340 943050741
121998376 943430501
689913499 770079066
586095107 933655238 …
(First line/number being the number of inputs)

My code is as below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class numberSpiral {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        long testN = scanner.nextLong();
        long r=0,c=0;
        while(testN-- > 0){
            r = scanner.nextLong();
            c = scanner.nextLong();
            if (c > r) {
                if (c % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(((c - 1) * (c - 1)) + 1 + (r - 1));
                } else
                    System.out.println(((c) * (c)) - (r - 1));
            } else {
                if(r % 2 == 0){
                    System.out.println(((r) * (r)) - (c - 1));
                } else
                    System.out.println(((r - 1) * (r - 1)) + 1 + (c - 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works for small inputs. I can't figure out how to optimize it better to reduce time. Time limit is: 1.00 s

Answer (score 3):

I assume you refer to https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1071/ .
Your Algorithm itself is fine as far is i can tell.

The Problem is the large amount of inputs that need to need to be read(Testcases=100000), which Scanner cant provide within the 1s time limit.
A BufferedReader should offer the performance needed for this.(See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-in-java-in-competitive-programming/ for more information).
The same might apply to System.out.println in which case it would be better to use a BufferedWriter

Answer (score 0):

usually calculation is faster than branching, so you may also try this:

```
         if (c > r) {
            int even = c % 2
            System.out.println(((c - 1*even) * (c - 1*even)) + 1*even + (r - 1));
        } else {
            int odd = 1-(r % 2)
            System.out.println(((r - 1*odd) * (r - 1*odd)) + 1*odd + (c - 1));
        }
```